# Why is the credentials option required for the CredentialsProvider?

Tags: typescript, next.js, credentials, next-auth

Many code examples for the NextAuth.js credentials provider that are using custom sign in pages do not include the credentials option in the CredentialsProvider. As stated in the documentiaion (https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials#example) the credentials option's purpose is to automatically "generate a suitable form on the sign in page" based on the properties appended to this option.
As I am using a custom sign in page I do not need these automaically generated fields because I coded them manually as also suggested in the documentation (https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages#credentials-sign-in)
As I am using Typescript it is throwing a type error when not providing the credentials option. As I do not need it I would like to leave it out. Is there a solution for my problem or is the credentials option required and needed for other reasons?

Code example with credentials option:

```
...
providers: [
  CredentialsProvider({
    name: "Credentials",
    credentials: {
      username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
      password: {  label: "Password", type: "password" }
    },
    async authorize(credentials, req) {
      const user = { id: 1, name: "J Smith", email: "jsmith@example.com" }

      if (user) {
        return user
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
  })
]
...
```

Code example without credentials option:

```
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
...
providers: [
  CredentialsProvider({
    name: "Credentials",
    async authorize(credentials, req) {
      const user = { id: 1, name: "J Smith", email: "jsmith@example.com" }

      if (user) {
        return user
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
  })
]
...
```

PS: Even the name option is not really neccessary when using a custom sign up page. I would like to be able to exclude that too...

Answer (score 0):

In NextAuth.js, the **credentials** option in the **CredentialsProvider** is not strictly required, but it serves a specific purpose. As you mentioned, its primary role is to automatically generate a suitable form on the sign-in page based on the properties defined within the **credentials** object.

If you are using a custom sign-in page and have manually coded your form fields, you can safely omit the **credentials** option. However, if you are using TypeScript and encounter type errors due to the missing **credentials** option, you have a few options:

1. **Provide a Dummy credentials Object:**

You can provide an empty or dummy credentials object to satisfy TypeScript type checking. This way, you can keep your custom sign-in page and avoid type errors. Here's an example:

```
import { CredentialsProvider } from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const credentials = {}; // Empty credentials object

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      credentials,
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        // Your custom authorization logic
      },
    }),
    // Other providers...
  ],
  // Other NextAuth options...
});
```

2. **Type Casting:**

If you prefer not to have an empty credentials object, you can use type casting to satisfy TypeScript. This tells TypeScript that the credentials object is of type any, effectively bypassing type checking for that specific property. Here's an example:

```
import { CredentialsProvider } from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const credentials = {} as any; // Type casting to any

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      credentials,
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        // Your custom authorization logic
      },
    }),
    // Other providers...
  ],
  // Other NextAuth options...
});
```

Both of these approaches allow you to omit the credentials option while still satisfying TypeScript's type checking. Just keep in mind that you may want to revisit the credentials option in the future if you decide to switch back to the NextAuth.js auto-generated form fields for your sign-in page.